# Is this Comonadic?

Tags: category-theory, monads

##### Question:

I will first state the question, then do explanation of terminology below.

All categories should be considered as cocomplete stable $\infty$-categories, and colimits, limits etc are the corresponding homotopy version. I will use dg category as a model.

Consider the following representation categories of quivers (over field $\mathbb{C}$)

$$ C = Rep_{dg} (\bullet \gets \bullet \to \bullet) , \quad D = Rep_{dg}(\bullet,\bullet)$$
Consider the following pair of adjoint functors
$$L: C \leftrightarrow D: R \quad L (a \gets b \to c) = (b, d=ho\varinjlim(a \gets b \to c) ), \quad R(b, d) = (d \gets (b \oplus d) \to d) $$

(Intuitively speaking, $C$ is the rep of a biCartesian square, and map to $D$ is restriction to the upper-left and bottom-right nodes. )

Let $\Omega = LR$ be the comonad acting on $D$. Is the "decomposition" functor
$\tilde L: C \to CoMod_\Omega(D)$
an equivalence of category?

I don't know how to tell apart the $\tilde L$-images of the following two objects:  $(0 \gets \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C})$ and $(\mathbb{C} \gets \mathbb{C} \to 0)$.

##### Background

(The following review is for the naive categories, not the infinity category version. I don't know what is the correct upgrade to $\infty$-category due to lack of knowledge in $\infty$-categories. I assume one needs to make $\Omega \rightrightarrows \Omega\Omega$ longer into  cosimplicial diagram, but don't know how to spell this out.)

Recall certain definitions about comonad. Let $L: C \leftrightarrow D: R$ be a pair of adjoint functors. Let $\Omega = LR: D \to D$ be the associated comonad, with counit map $\epsilon: \Omega \to 1_D$ and comultiplication $\Delta=L(1 \to RL)R: \Omega \to \Omega \Omega$.

Let $CoMod_\Omega(D)$ be the category, whose object is a pair $(x \in D, a: x \to \Omega(x))$, where the co-action morphism $a$ satisfies condition
$$ 1_x = \epsilon(x) \circ a: x \to \Omega(x) \to x$$
and that
$$ x \to \Omega(x) \rightrightarrows \Omega\Omega(x) $$
is a equalizer, where one arrow comes from $(\Omega \to \Omega \Omega)$ applied to $x$, and another comes from $\Omega$ applied to $x \to \Omega x$.

We say $L$ is *comonadic*, if the "decomposition" functor
$$ C \to CoMod_\Omega(D), \quad c \mapsto (Lc, L(1 \to RL)(c)) $$
is an equivalence of category.

For Barr-Beck (co)monadicity theorem, see [Branter's notes](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/brantner/Koszul_lectures.html). In lecture 2 and 3, you can find the classical version, and in lecture 4 and 5 the $\infty$-category version.

Comment: Something that I realized after discussion with someone else: the comodule structure is not just a map $a: x \to \Omega x$ that satisfies certain equality. No, nothing is equal on the nose. "Equality is extra data, not just a condition". It is like we are not just asking a two chain maps to be equal on the nose, but they are chain-homotopic $f-g = dh + hd$. I think it is this additional structure that allows one to tell apart this two objects.

Comment: The context here is very unclear. You’re using homotopy pushouts and homotopy coalgebras, so are we talking $\infty$-categories? Homotopy categories of representations?

Comment: @KevinArlin Sorry for the confusion. I wasn't sure what the correct setup should be. I was trying to avoid infinity category in the beginning, and formulate the problem in abelian category, then I realized that is wrong. I am not sure how to setup the problem using infinity category (based on simplicial set), so I will just use dg category now.

Comment: I don’t really know whether there even exists a monadicity theorem for dg categories, unfortunately.